# How bad is using abstract class for data objects

Tags: java

While writing UI automation tests I come across forms with many fields and instead of passing numerous arguments to test methods I create classes to quickly set form data. So if there is a sign up form I create SignUpDataObjectClass which would have instance variable corresponding to form fields i.e.

```
public class SignUpFormObject() {
 private username;
 private password;

 public SignUpFormObject setUsername(String username) {
  this.username = username;
  return this;
 }

 public String getUsername() {
  return username;
 }

 public SignUpFormObject setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
  return this;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

 // Util method to set signup test data. Test method can use it on the fly
 public static SignUpFormObject setSignUpData() {
  SignUpFormObject dataObject = new SignUpFormObject();
  dataobject.setUsername("test user").setPassword("password");

  return dataobject;    
 }   
}
```

And then I came across a scenario when it did not make sense to have single data object class for a form. The form is related to creation of Coupon and then there could be different categories of Coupon. For sake of brevity I would limit the number of fields here. So there would be two kinds of coupons - offer and printable. Both of them will have coupon name and one field specific to offer 
(let's consider it - offer expire date) and another for printable (let's consider it - printable code)

So I decided to create Coupon abstract class which would have all common fields and then CouponOffer and CouponPrintable classes would extend Coupon class and add their own fields i.e.

```
public abstract class Coupon {
 private String couponname;

 public Coupon setCouponname(String couponName) {
  this.couponname = couponname;
 }  

 public String getCouponname() {
  return couponname;
 }
```

And CouponOffer class comes here -

```
public class CouponOffer extends Coupon {
 private String offerExpireDate;

 public CouponOffer setOfferExpireDate(String offerExpireDate) {
  this.offerExpireDate = offerExpireDate;
  return this;
 }  

 public String getOfferExpireDate() {
  return offerExpireDate;
 }

 // Util method to set coupon offer data
 public static CouponOffer setCouponOfferData() {

  CouponOffer couponOffer = new CouponOffer();    
  couponOffer.setCouponname("test coupon");    
  couponOffer.setOfferExpireDate("31/12/2013");   
  return couponOffer();
 }
}
```

I am willing to know if using abstract class is bad approach here and there are better solutions available.

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't `setSignUpData` and `setCouponOfferData` be static methods?

Comment: Will it be an issue with I run tests in parallel?

Comment: Nope, you are creating a new instance of couponOffer in it anyway. So it is totally thread safe to make it static.

Comment: though I am no master of thread I see your point now. Will edit my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a good solution.

Your class `CouponOffer` just adds the `offerExpireDate` functionality. Any other functionalities (attributes) of `Coupon` can be reused by other implementations.

And no need to repeat the trivial `Coupon` fields for every implementation

Comment: Actually I had started with writing just one class Coupon initially having all fields for all types of Coupons, but class grew horrible in size and I found me scrolling up and down constantly. Hence I though of dividing them in multiple classes....

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good solution except that the base `Coupon` class does not need to be `abstract`. You are creating a class hierarchy which is a major part of what OO Programming is supposed to be all about.

Comment: I declare it abstract coz it does not make sense to instantiate it as it is incomplete in itself. Though I could have used private constructor or something but I though abstract class fits in best